# clicking a recyclerView Item takes me to the top of activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a included three layouts in my activity_main.xml. the 3rd layout contains a recyclerview with some items. when i click any item of the recyclerview, the app redirects me to the top of the activity. i am unable to understand why this is happening so.

my main_activity.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBase"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Activities.BasketActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <ScrollView
              android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:fillViewport="true"
              android:scrollbars="vertical"
              map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
              map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
              map:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include3"
            layout="@layout/address_information_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/map" />


        <include
            android:id="@+id/include4"
            layout="@layout/collection_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
            map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include3"/>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include5"
            layout="@layout/delivery_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
            map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include4"/>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include6"
            layout="@layout/your_items_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
            map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include5"/>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include7"
            layout="@layout/checkout_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
            map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            map:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include6"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

I have also set android:focusableInTouchMode="true". but the result is coming the same

Comment: this is happening because your app is crashing.. *what exactly are you performing on the click of the item* ?

Comment: on clicking the recyclerview, i am incrementing the count of my quantity of product in the cart. i think i found what the problem is. the first layout has an editText inside it and when the activity is created, the focus is set to this edittext. when i scroll down and click on recyclerview, the focus again goes back to that editText.now how can i manage that. ?

Comment: why edittext is getting focused on click of item ? are you `requestingFoucus` forcibly ?

Comment: set property in recyclerview `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

Comment: @SantanuSur I've not requesting any focus right now